# android:fitsSystemWindows not working on Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I have a fragment call reload fragment below. Parent activity is MainActivity. I attached manifest file code which related to activity.  When I click in the edittext bottom buttons cover edittext fields with the keyboard. I added android:fitsSystemWindows property in the manifest file. Is there anything missing in my code?

[image]

> Fragment Layout

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/fragments_background"
            tools:context=".ui.fragments.BillPaymentFragment">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/wallet"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@color/wolletColor"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_50dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/wallet" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_4dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/wallet_remains"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                        android:text="3450.00 LKR"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_16dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/wallet_remains"
                        android:textColor="@color/gray"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_12dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_60dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_20dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                            android:text="Mobile No"
                            android:textColor="@color/borderAndFont"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_20dp"></TextView>

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/reload_mobile_number"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text"
                            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                            android:hint="@string/mobile_number"
                            android:inputType="phone"
                            android:textColor="@color/borderAndFont"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                            android:text="@string/amount"
                            android:textColor="@color/borderAndFont"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_20dp"></TextView>

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/reload_amount"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edit_text"
                            android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
                            android:hint="@string/amount_hint"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:textColor="@color/borderAndFont"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_6dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/secondary_button"
                        android:text="Cancel"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_proceed"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_6dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/primary_button"
                        android:text="Proceed"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

> AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
      <activity
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
                android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

Comment: did you tried with android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: @BunnyYes, Same Result.

Comment: Makes sense. It is the parent Activity that has to set android:fitsSystemWindows, not the child fragment.

Comment: @lionscribe you mean that "android:fitsSystemWindows="true"" should put in parent activity layout ?

Comment: use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: @lionscribe I have already added "android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to main activity also.

Comment: @RajithaPerera add scroll view in your XML.

Comment: @nimi0112- Solved Issue.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true` and `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to the Main Activity won't work.

You have to add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true` to the parent layout of that particular **Fragment xml** file. And in the `java` class of the `Fragment` in your `onCreateView` you have to add `windowSoftInputMode` like this.

```
getActivity()
            .getWindow()
            .setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Hope this works for you. Let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
activity?.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.